# Build Error with Request Location Accuracy Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am building a `Phonegap app` using `Visual Studio Tools` for `Apache Cordova`.

I am trying to get a native dialog to take user to / enable location services and for the same I am using the `Request Location Accuracy Plugin` from [HERE](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy).

However when I add that plugin from `GIT`, I get the below build error and I am unable to build the project.

```
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>  * What went wrong:
1>  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
1>  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
1>     > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+.
1>       Searched in the following locations:
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
1>       Required by:
1>           :android:unspecified
1>
```

The `config.xml` shows the plugin installed as below statement is present in the `config.xml`.

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" version="1.0.1" />
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

PS - I have already enabled `Google Play` services in the `SDK Manager`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Added another "EXTRA" and now it builds successfully. Looks like we also need to add `"Android Support Repository"` which in the latest versions of SDK manager is known as `"Local Maven Repository for Support Libraries"`.

Once I added that, it worked fine and I can build the application perfectly.

Comment: so what was different in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I raised this issue on the `github` [repository](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.git) of `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy` and Mr. Dave Alden responded within no time. He has updated the project's `README`.

> IMPORTANT: This plugin depends on the Google Play Services library, so you must install the "Google Repository" package under the "Extras" section in Android SDK Manager. Otherwise the build will fail.

So install "Google Repository" under "Extras" in your SDK manager if you haven't yet and try building again.

[image: screenshot of sdk manager]

Once have a look at the updated documentation of the [repository](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.git)

Comment: As I mentioned, I had already added Google Play Services. So that is not an issue.